# Using celery 4 without Redis

Tags: python, celery

My site write with django. I need to run some task in the background of container(I using ec2).
Recently, I research Celery. But, it required redis or queue server to run. It makes I cannot using celery because I mustn't install something else.
Question: Can I setup celery stand alone? If yes, how to do this? If no, Are we have any alternative, which can install stand alone?

Comment: Celery needs external service for tasks queue (workers are picking those tasks from queue) so it cannot be stand alone. You have to decide which broker fits to you. Maybe Amazon SQS? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.3.0/getting-started/brokers/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is - no, you cannot use Celery without a broker (Redis, RabbitMQ, or any other from the [list of supported brokers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html)).

I am not aware of a service that does both (queue management AND execution environment for your tasks). Best services follow the UNIX paradigm - "do one thing, and do it right". Service you described above would have to do two different, non-trivial things and that is probably why most likely such service does not exist (at least not in the Python world).

Comment: In rails framework, we have delay job same with celery. It don't need broker

Comment: Distributed? So multiple instances of your job can run concurrently on multiple servers?

Comment: I was considering using something like `os.system("start /b python myscript.py args")` to run a background process. Thoughts?